# EditText sending messages won't allow special characters

Tags: android, parsing

I have a chat application that allows sending messages so long as there are no special characters within ie. no commas, apostrophes...etc. I am implementing with an EditTest as such:

```
    CharSequence message;

    message = enteredMessage.getText();

    sendMessage(from, to, message.toString());
```

How can I reformulate to allow for commas, apostrophes and other normally used sentence constructs without the service having issues sending?

Comment: show me your sendMessage method

Answer (score 1):

a good start is to urlEncode the string :`URLEncoder.encode(myString, "UTF-8")`

for example this

```
try {
        Log.d("URL ENCODING", URLEncoder.encode("My message has a lot of stuff, ; # $ ?", "UTF-8").toString());
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Outputs

**My+message+has+a+lot+of+stuff%2C+%3B+%23+%24+%3F**

Answer (score 0):

Replace your special character with subsequent character in the message

```
“   %22
<   %3C

>   %3E
&   %26

+   %2B
#   %23

%   %25

*   %2A

!   %21

,   %2C

‘   %27

\   %5C

=   %3D


€   %E2%82%AC
```